# External User gets 403 error while trying to update list item using Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

We are using Graph API to create and update SharePoint list item. We have assigned external users to site's member group. External users get authorized to the domain using AAD and can successfully add and view list items. However, when the same external user, during the same session, tries to modify the list item properties for the item s/he has created, the system throws a `403 Forbidden` error. Here is the `PATCH` request that we are sending to SharePoint. The access token is the same that was used to create the list item. The list contains documents in it.

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mydomain.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/lists/mylist/items/1780/fields

{
  "CaseNumber": "13XX17101310238",
  "AppointmentID": "13App17101310238",
  "DocumentURL":
    "%7B0499F164-3320-4B66-A2B7-B51D1C73F502%7D&file=2018-04-26%2015.45.43.8965PM.docx"
}
```

Any idea where we are losing it? I am intrigued by the `403` since the document has been uploaded by the same user, in the same session so the authorization shall not have been an issue here. Our complete code snippet is as follows

```csharp
public async Task<string> UpdateListItemsByItemID(string listItemID, string documentURL)
{
    string responseString = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        string addItemJsonString = "{\"CaseNumber\":\"13XX17101310238\",\"AppointmentID\":\"13App17101310238\",\"DocumentURL\":\"https://document\"}";
        string requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mydomain.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/lists/mylist/items/1782/fields";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), requestUrl);
        message.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        message.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        message.Content = new StringContent(addItemJsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        else
            responseString = "Error in response";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        responseString = "Exception: " + ex.Message;
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

The permission scope of the user is given below. It is the same for all the external users where they are pretty much allowed to do everything

[image: Permission Scopoe]

The request message is as follows

```
{
    Method: PATCH, 
    RequestUri: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mydomain.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/lists/mylist/items/1780/fields", 
    Version: 2.0, 
    Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, 
    Headers: {  
        Accept: application/json  
        Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFEWDhHQ2k2SnM2U0s4MlRzRDJQYjdybFJMbUdDcDFvb2pzdjdXSjYwX1EtNk83UkFZVTFxRXlqYTQ4TzcxbUJzSnJ2blpicGpneFdJbjQzZ2JwcmZVa081SG1CM09xUnJhc1Fzdlp3OU9HdVNBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiRlNpbXVGckZOb0Mwc0pYR212MTNuTlpjZURjIiwia2lkIjoiRlNpbXVGckZOb0Mwc0pYR212MTNuTlpjZURjIn0.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.xsdOu-5xoLXk5Galaoy0YQNvXzb3K_W0sL--_y7EmM-ubLE5nCWdWhf81gIqM2ONcEGSejVgmWvOlQZqiv8mccrhONHZ3lS4Jf_SsjxRWmVINQ8Q-3M_2RF60tFGQ0Cf6hWMGYGO33OfZsLIf1Dn5PSt7iWKUrNNgiJIks8imcb7KQwzy24Qsh8OTJPmN_0Wec18d0dE2tVjCOqEDACpG7yp5xmea8vM8UE0dyzCM7iRhwM2Ez6Mv-XsFnd663BlyzL6JUN8WHemjv9q_P2IcvCt9Jf2cN3g0CBtj2d7uUlgEpTZ_Tz652BMYQbbFMeigvOkIjG-VKMYldQ6FuKjvA  
        Content-Type: text/plain; 
        charset=utf-8  
        Content-Length: 28
    }
}
```

The complete error code is as follows:

```
{
    StatusCode: 403, 
    ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', 
    Version: 1.1, 
    Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, 
    Headers:{  
        client-request-id: 1f5f91af-32d8-4a41-9375-8495a675d657  
        Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000  
        request-id: 1f5f91af-32d8-4a41-9375-8495a675d657  
        Transfer-Encoding: chunked  
        x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"SouthEast Asia","Slice":"SliceA","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_1","ADSiteName":"SIN"}
    }
    Duration: 4018.2188  
    Cache-Control: private  
    Date: Fri, 27 Apr 2018 06:55:16 GMT  
    Content-Type: application/json}
}
```

[image: Error Response]

The response we get back is as follows

```
Response : {StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{  client-request-id: 03cc9d52-cc1f-4889-b9b5-4ca14bdc0aec Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 request-id: 03cc9d52-cc1f-4889-b9b5-4ca14bdc0aec Transfer-Encoding: chunked x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Europe","Slice":"SliceA","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_24","ADSiteName":"DUB"}}  Duration: 413.1109 Cache-Control: private Date: Tue, 01 May 2018 13:23:39 GMT Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 256}}

Response Content: { "error": { "code": "accessDenied, message: The caller does not have permission to perform the action.", "innerError": { "request-id": "03cc9d52-cc1f-4889-b9b5-4ca14bdc0aec", "date": "2018-05-01T13:23:39" }}}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error? `403 Forbidden` is simply the error code, there should be several other properties returned in the error object. Please also include the permission scopes you've selected.

Comment: @marc I have uploaded the snapshot of permission scope in AAD and the complete error code for your reference my friend.

Comment: @marc Any suggestions my friend?

Comment: What you've added is the HTTP response but not the content. I'm looking for the JSON content of the response. Also, have you gone through the Admin Consent process? Most of these scopes require consent before a user can actually use them.

Comment: @marc I have added the response content to the post my friend. Please advise of your thoughts.

Comment: @marc The consent is given by the admin in AAD. Trick is that the guest user can upload a document yo the library without problem. It errors out when it tries to grab the same document it uploaded to update its values in the list. Please advise of your thoughts.

Comment: Do they have access to the file through SharePoint? Remember that Graph cannot provide more access than the user would have through the traditional UI.

Comment: Yes they do. They can do all this stuff via portal. What intrigues me is that they can upload the doc which I think requires more privilege than updating the same document.

Comment: That is not always the case. They may have access to the `drive` resource but not the `site` resource for example. That would prevent them from updating metadata in the Document Library even if they're able to upload/download items from the `drive` behind it.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're not using the `DriveItem.Id` as it's `ListItem.Id` correct? They are different (a `ListItem` is sequentually numbered, a `DriveItem` uses a UUID).

Comment: @marc You are correct we are using ListItem.id (1782) in this case. I am not sure how do I check if these users have access to site resource. They can access the library and do all sorts of things from the portal but I may be missing the work to grant them access to site resource in AAD. I do have assigned them all the permissions via admin consent through "Grant Permission" button. Not sure if I need to do something beyond that. Feeling lost now :(

Comment: @marc Further investigation reveals that the Guest users are not able to perform any action on the Site resource. Scratching my head to find out how to enable access to site resource for these users. Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: @marc How do I give permission to my external users to access site resources via graph api? They can access them from portal but not from code.

Comment: @marc When I grant "Read" access to the external user for the root site collection (Team Site) then the read operation succeeds on the subsite as well. However this is not a much reasonable solution for allowing access to the external users. Pretty much the same scenario that is mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672387/microsoft-graph-why-is-root-site-read-access-needed-to-access-subsite-in-anoth . Is it a Graph API limitation or is there a way to get around this hurdle. Your help is urgently requested.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a gap in current implementation of Graph API for SharePoint online. While the external user gets access to the "drive" endpoint by assigning them access to a library, the access to the "site" resource is not granted until that external user is granted a "read" access to the root site collection. It means that even if you have created a totally separate site collection (X) for the external users, ***you still will have to give them "read" access to your "root" site collection e.g., yourdomain.sharepoint.com***, in order for you to grant them access to site collection (X) via Graph API. I am not sure why it is so but so far it is the only way to make Graph API work with external users for SharePoint Sites. Hopefully this changes sooner than later though because like this it is pretty much useless to use Graph API.